# Node.js sporadic 'ECONNREFUSED' error on request.get

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, loopbackjs, nw.js

I'm having a sporadic issue with my Node/loopback server. My setup is as follows:

EDIT: My node version is v4.2.4, I'm running Node on Windows 10 Professional.

**Client side:**

- nw.js client that traverses the local file-system and computes the MD5 value of files.
- Using a `request.post`, the client sends the hash of the file to the server in the format `'fileHash: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'` (that's just an example hash, I know it's an empty file)

  ```
  function checkHash (fileHash){
  request.post({
      headers: {'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/checkBoths/hashcheck',
      method: 'POST',
      form: {
         fileHash: fileHash
      }
  }, function(error, response, body){
     if(error) {
      console.log(error);
     } else {
      console.log(response.statusCode, body);
     }
  });

  }
  ```

**Server side:**

- Node/loopback server running at `localhost:3000`.
- The `hashCheck` function is meant to read the data that's posted from the client and query a MySQL database which is for a match of the hash.
- The response from the server will be in the format `goodResult : true` if the hash exists in the database or `goodResult : false` if not.

  ```
  var request = require('request');

  module.exports = function (CheckBoth) {

  var goodResult;

  CheckBoth.hashCheck = function (fileHash, cb) {

  requestGood(fileHash);

    function requestGood (fileHash) {

  request.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/Goodhashes/' + fileHash + '/exists', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      goodResult = JSON.parse(body).exists;
    }
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  });
  console.log(goodResult);
    }

  cb( goodResult);
  };


  CheckBoth.remoteMethod(
  'hashCheck',
  {
    accepts: {arg: 'fileHash', type: 'string'},
    returns: [{arg: 'goodResult', type: 'string'}]
  }
  );
  };
  ```

**Issue:**

The server can respond with ~1000 queries before the following appears throughout the responses:

```
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3000 }
```

I've tried putting in different callbacks within the server code but that has not made any difference. I think I should probably throttle the requests to the server but I don't know how to achieve this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of node are you running?

Comment: @migg I'm running v4.2.4

Comment: Hmm... your parameter is called `callback`, but you are calling `cb`. Maybe you are creating a memleak with it until the server refuses connections?

Comment: @migg Whoops... That's actually an error in how I copied the file over. In my actual code they're both called cb. I'll edit my question to reflect that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Now `badResult` and `mhrResult` are still undefined. And as you are injecting CheckBoth into the module, but you are changing it inside, you still probably are leaking memory. You should debug how much memory your app consumes.

Comment: @migg Sorry for me being an idiot, those are two variables I had in earlier for different functions that I'm not using any more. I've removed those and the code is still working the same way. Cheers.

Comment: Does it leak memory? You can watch your memory consumption on your machine or with node-inspector for example.

Comment: @migg It looks like it might be leaking memory. The node server is going from ~70MB of memory used to ~250MB used in the space of 5 minutes. I figured that this would be normal as the client is sending around 60k requests in that time.

Comment: It is normal if no GC event took place, but if GC kicks in and you still use more memory, its bad. But 250MB does not sound like an explanation for refused connections... maybe someone else has another idea.

Comment: @migg Thanks for your time anyway. I appreciate it. If you have any more thoughts I'm all ears!

Answer (score 1):

The ulimit default for most systems is 1024. See the manual for limits.conf (http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf).

While @migg is correct about ensuring no memory leaks in your application and its process handling tuning the system for high loads is also normal procedure for quite a few applications.

Try this and see if it helps;

$ ulimit -n 65535

Edit: I have not tested this but here is a document from ibm regarding Windows; http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21392080

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm developing on a Windows 10 machine. I'm not sure if you can set the ulimit in Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It seems that Microsoft’s Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications (SUA) or Windows Services for UNIX (SFU) were both deprecated in Windows 8.1 Enterprise so I can't modify those registry values as they don't exist on Windows 10.

Comment: I haven't used Windows on a regular basis for over a decade but even on Windows 2002 Server you could add registry key if they didn't exist and they would influence the functionality.

Comment: I've added the registry key and restarted the machine but I'm still experiencing the same issue. I also allowed all traffic on port 3000 in the firewall to see if that helped but there's no difference. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: After a bit of digging around, I think there's a default rate-limit built into loopback but I don't know how to configure it. If I figure it out, I'll update my question to help someone else out. https://docs.strongloop.com/display/LGW/Configuring+policies#Configuringpolicies-Configuringratelimiting

Comment: @Oddball I work for StrongLoop, there is no rate limiting imposed in LoopBack of any kind. What you're linking to there is our API gateway which allows the developer to rate limit access to their server. Since you aren't using our gateway, this is not what is happening.

Comment: @jakerella Thanks for the clarification. I'll update my post to reflect that.